# How can send a json with a BinaryArray?

Tags: javascript, http

I try to send an Json object together with a BinaryArray. If I use the fetch api, the binaryArray Becomes an empty object.

const payload = { name: "dieter", age: 41, attachments: [BinaryArray, BinaryArray. ..]}

fetch(URL, { method: "POST", body: payload}).

Comment: The first argument to `fetch` is the URL... or a Request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a subset of Javascript and, as such, only supports numbers, booleans, strings, objects, and arrays.  As such, you will have to encode your binary content in a format that can be expressed as a string.  Base64 is probably the best approach.  You can do this by calling the toString("base64") method for the buffer.